# Integral with parameter: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin \left ( ax \right )}{\sin x\ +\ \cos x}\, {\rm d}x $

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> Is it possible to express in a closed form the integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin \left ( ax \right )}{\sin x+\cos x}\, {\rm d}x,\,\,\, a\in \mathbb{N}\quad?$$

Well, I find it very difficult. Well, I know how to express the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,{\rm d}x \;=\; \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\, {\rm d}x\;=\;\frac{\pi}{4}$$
by applying the substitution $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$, but in general I don't have a clue.

If someone could help me, that would be nice!

Comment: Nice question. Wolfram Alpha can't find a closed formula.

Comment: After a substitution $t=x-\pi/4$ we get $I=\sqrt2\sin\frac{\pi a}{4}\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos ax}{\cos x}\,dx$. The last integral could be treated using recurrence relation $\cos ax=2\cos x\cos(a-1)x-\cos(a-2)x$. I hope this might help.

Comment: @CuriousGuest Well, how possible is to evaluate the last integral? I think I've seen it somewhere before... Nice approach though, thnx!

Comment: @Tolaso It's easy to integrate it from 0 to $\pi$ (in this case $I_a=I_{a-2}$), but for segment $[0,\pi/4]$ the recurrence relation isn't so nice.

Comment: @CuriousGuest That is why I asked that. Therefore , I don't know.. I only know the integrals you've mentioned $\int_0^\pi \frac{sin ax}{\sin x}\, dx$ and that other with cosine. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are really interested in a closed form formula then let's consider the integral

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{e^{inx}}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}dx $$

where your integral equals to the imaginary part of $I$. $I$ can have the closed form in terms of the [Lerch zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function)

> $$ I = \frac{(1-i) e^{\frac{i\pi n}{2}}} {2}\left( \Phi \left( -i,1,\frac{n+1}{2}\right) - \Phi \left( i,1, \frac{n+1}{2} \right ) \right)   . $$

**Note:**

> 1) Maple $17$ can not give an answer for this integral! I do not know about Maple 18. Already a different form for the answer, computed by Mathematica $9$, was posted.

2) The real part of $I$ evaluates the integral

> $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(nx)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}dx. $$

Comment: This one is beautiful ! Thanks for this answer

Comment: I have a problem : for $n=1$ the result from your formula seems to be $\frac{\log (2)}{2}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks for the comment. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: It gave me $\pi/4+i\pi/4$. Make sure you copied it correctly.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Great ! Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: @Tolaso: You are very welcome.

Comment: What do you get for $n=4 k$ ? I am just unable to find my error.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: It should be zero.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal What is the result for $n=2015$, just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

This is
$$
-\Biggl(\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  n} \biggl(e^{\frac{i \pi  n}{2}} \biggl((n-1) \biggl(e^{\frac{i \pi  n}{2}} \, _2F_1\biggl(1,\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+3}{2};-i\biggr)\\+i \, _2F_1\biggl(1,\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+3}{2};i\biggr)\biggr)+i (n+1) \, _2F_1\biggl(1,\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3-n}{2};i\biggr)\biggr)\\+(n+1) \, _2F_1\biggl(1,\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3-n}{2};-i\biggr)\biggr)\Biggr)/(n^2-1)
$$
according to Wolfram Mathematica$^{TM}$ 9

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer from Vladimir but I had fun computing the integral for some values of $n$ and I let that for your curiosity.

Let $$I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin \left ( ax \right )}{\sin x+\cos x}\, {\rm d}x$$ $$I_1=\frac{\pi }{4}$$ $$I_2=2-\sqrt{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ $$I_3=1-\frac{\pi }{4}$$ $$I_4=0$$ $$I_5=1-\frac{\pi }{4}$$ $$I_6=\sqrt{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\frac{14}{15}$$ $$I_7=\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{2}{3}$$ $$I_8=0$$ $$I_9=\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{2}{3}$$ $$I_{10}=\frac{454}{315}-\sqrt{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ $$I_{11}=\frac{13}{15}-\frac{\pi }{4}$$ $$I_{12}=0$$ We can understand that the general formula must be far away from simple.

Comment: Well, I had computed the three first values of the integral (that is for $a=1, 2, 3$) got the same results.. and then I gave up. OK, Vladimirs answer is good but I think that a closed form may not exist... What I observe now , from your post,  is that every 4 four values the integral equals zero. That may gives us a pattern.. who knows?

Comment: There is closed form ... which is a nightmare (at least, to me). The fact that every four values the integral equals zero is obvious since the numerator is $\sin(4kx)$ and the integration is between $0$ and $\frac{\pi }{2}$. Good luck and enjoy ! Cheers :)

Comment: I'd imagine that it'd simplify things somewhat to divide into cases of $n$ mod 4 owing to the distinct difference in behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the integral with $x=t+\frac\pi4$
$$I_a=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin ax }{\sin x+\cos x}dx= \sqrt2 \sin\frac{a\pi}4\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\frac{\cos a t}{\cos t}dt
$$
and note that $\frac{\cos a t}{\cos t} =2\cos(a-1)t-\frac{\cos (a-2) t}{\cos t}  $, which affords recursive integration to result in the following general close-forms for either odd $a=2n+1$ or even $a=2n$
\begin{align}
&I_{2n+1}=(-1)^{[\frac{n+1}2]}\bigg(\frac\pi4+\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{n+1}2]}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\bigg)\\
&I_{2n}=-\sin\frac{n\pi}2\bigg(\sqrt2\coth^{-1}\sqrt2+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2(-1)^{ [\frac k2+1]}}{2k-1}\bigg)
\end{align}