# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin (2015x)}{\sin x+\cos x}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the definite integral
>   $$
> I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin (2015x)}{\sin x+\cos x}\;dx
> $$

**My Attempt:**

Using the identity

$$
\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\;dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)\;dx
$$

Exchange $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$ for $x$ in the integral to get

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin (2015x)}{\sin x+\cos x}\;dx &= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2015\pi}{2}-2015 x\right)}{\cos x+\sin x}\;dx\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos (2015x)}{\sin x+\cos x}\;dx
\end{align}
$$

How can I complete the solution from this point?

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872470/integral-with-parameter). As I mentioned there in a comment, using the substitution $t=x-\pi/4$ you can rewrite your integral as
$$I=\sqrt{2}\sin\frac{2015\pi}{4}\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos 2015x}{\cos x}\,dx=-\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos 2015x}{\cos x}\,dx=-I_{2015},$$
where $$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos nx}{\cos x}\,dx.$$
Now let us recall the identity $\cos nx=2\cos x\cos (n-1)x-\cos(n-2)x$, i.e. $$\frac{\cos nx}{\cos x}=2\cos (n-1)x-\frac{\cos(n-2)x}{\cos x}.$$ For $n=2015$ we have
$$I_{2015}=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos 2015x}{\cos x}\,dx=\frac{2}{2014}\sin\frac{2014\pi}{4}-I_{2013}=-\frac{1}{1007}-\frac{2}{2012}\sin\frac{2012\pi}{2}+I_{2011}=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{1007}+\frac{1}{1005}-I_{2009}=\ldots=\sum_{k=1}^{504} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}-I_1,$$ 
where
$I_1=\pi/4$. So
$$I=-I_{2015}=\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{k=1}^{504} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}.$$
Noting that $\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}$, you can also write it in the form
$$I=\sum_{k=505}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}\approx 0.0004960312578\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x\mapsto \frac \pi4-x$ and using the properties of odd and even functions transforms the integral
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2015 x\right)}{\cos x} d x \\
& =-\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin (2015 x)+\cos (2015 x)}{\cos x} d x \\
& =-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos (2015 x)}{\cos x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $I_m=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos (2 m+1) x}{\cos x} d x$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_m+I_{m-1} & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos (2 m+1) x+\cos (2 m-1) xd x}{\cos x} \\
& =2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos 2 m x \cos x}{\cos x} d x \\
& =2\left[\frac{\sin 2 m x}{2 m}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \\
& = \begin{cases}(-1)^{\frac{m-1}{2}} & \text { if } m \text { is odd } \\ 0 & \text { if } m \text { is even }\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
Using this induction formula, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{1007}  & =-I_{1006}-\frac{1}{1007} \\
& =I_{1005} +0-\frac{1}{1007} \\
& =-I_{1004}+\frac{1}{1005}-\frac{1}{1007} \\
&\vdots\\
& =-I_0+\sum_{n=1}^{504} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2 n-1}\\
& =-\frac \pi 4+ \sum_{n=1}^{504} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2 n-1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin (2015x)}{\sin x+\cos x}dx=-I_{1007}= \frac \pi 4+ \sum_{n=1}^{504} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2 n-1} }$$