# How could I show that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos (nx)}{\cos x}dx$ converges to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Consider $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos (nx)}{\cos x}dx$$

From here, I can show that $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos (nx)}{\cos x}dx > \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos (nx)dx \rightarrow 0$$ as $n$ approaches infinity, so I've constructed a lower bound for the integral.

However, I cannot see how to construct an upper bound that also converges to zero, so then I can squeeze the two integrals between two things which approach zero.

Comment: Do you know the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma or plancherels formula for the Fourier transform on $L^2([0,2\pi])$?

Comment: I do not know of them unfortunately. Is there a more elementary way of going about doing this?

Comment: The choice of $\pi/2$ as the upper limit was unfortunate. If we choose something smaller, then the integral does indeed approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This integral does not converge to 0 as $n \to \infty$.

**Case $n = 2m$.** In this case, the integrand has simple pole at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$$ \frac{\cos 2mx}{\cos x} \sim \frac{(-1)^m}{\frac{\pi}{2} - x} \quad \text{as } x \to \tfrac{\pi}{2},$$

and hence the integral diverges:

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos 2mx}{\cos x} \, dx = \begin{cases}
+\infty & \text{if } m \text{ is odd} \\
-\infty & \text{if } m \text{ is even}.
\end{cases} $$

**Case $n = 2m+1$.** In this case, the integral converges but the resulting sequence still does not converge. Indeed,

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(2m+1)x}{\cos x} \, dx + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(2m-1)x}{\cos x} \, dx
= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 2\cos(2mx) \, dx
= 0 $$

and iterating this relation $m$ times, we get

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(2m+1)x}{\cos x} \, dx = (-1)^m \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos x}{\cos x} \, dx = (-1)^m \frac{\pi}{2}. $$

Consequently, the integral does not converge even when we consider odd terms only.

Comment: Thank you for that.

I was hoping that the integral would converge to zero because I was reading this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873913/evaluation-of-int-0-frac-pi2-frac-sin-2015x-sin-x-cos-xdx

and thought that we could somehow prove the Leibniz Series by showing that the integral, which behaves like a remainder term, vanishes.

Comment: @Trogdor, As pointed out by **André Nicolas**, the upper bound $\pi/2$ was an unfortunate choice. Making this bound smaller, however small the decrement is, will make the sequence converge to 0.